# How to get which td clicked in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following table:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
   <tr data-uom_id="1" id="id-742">
     <td style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle; display: none;"><img src="left-arrow.png>"</td>
     <td style="width: 70%; text-align: left;" class="center">some text here</td>
     <td style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle;"><img src="right-arrow.png></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here my **`<tr>`** element has 3 **`<td>`**. Can I get which **`<td>`** is clicked? Please check attached image for more clarification.

[image]

Comment: How do you mean _is clicked_? Do you have an event bound to them, or do you want to know which ones been clicked previously?

Comment: I want to move 'center' <td> to the left when click on left <td> , same for right and center, value 2 should move to left , right and center on their respective clicks.Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect which <td> is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470251/how-to-detect-which-td-is-clicked)

Comment: @guradio , my question is different that you suggested, I don't want to get text of clicked <td> , rather I want to know which <td> (1st or 2nd or 3rd) is clicked ?

Comment: if you can get the text of the clicked td for sure you know which td is clicked right? @SachinVairagi

Comment: @SachinVairagi - check my answer. I am a bit confused though, you want the whole `<td>` to move to left or only the `text-align` to be changed to `left`?

Comment: I mentioned values 1,2,3 just for example , I have image in 1st and 3rd td, let me update my question.Thank You for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code:

Edit - changed the code as per requirement

```js
function whichOne() {
    //alert(this.id);
    document.getElementById("center").style.textAlign = this.id;
} 

document.getElementById('left').onclick = whichOne;
document.getElementById('right').onclick = whichOne;
document.getElementById('center').onclick = whichOne;
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td style="width: 15%;" id="left">1</td>
     <td style="width: 70%; text-align: center;" id="center">2</td>
     <td style="width: 15%;" id="right">3</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I copied you codes into separate php file , but it is not working.

Comment: u copied the HTML part into one PHP file and did u import the JS or added the script inside the `head` tag?

Answer (score 1):

Once you bind the click handler, you could get the index:

```js
$("#id-742 td").click(function(){
   var numClicked = $(this).index()+1;
   console.log(numClicked)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
   <tr data-uom_id="1" id="id-742">
     <td style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle; display: none;">1</td>
     <td style="width: 70%; text-align: left;" class="center">2</td>
     <td style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle;">3</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a JS solution:

```
function whichTd() {
   var td = document.getElementById("id-742").children;
   for (var i=0; i < td.length; i++){
      td[i].addEventListener("click", function(i) {
            alert("td"+(i+1)+"has been clicked");
      }(i),false);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the click cell using the following code:

```
$('body').on('click', 'td', function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$("#id-742 td").click(function(){
    //function to run when a td is clicked
});
```

Inside the function you can access the clicked td using `this`.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a pure JavaScript solution:**

```
var
    td = document.getElementById("id-742").children,
    i = 0;

Array.from(td).forEach(function() {
    td[i].onclick = function(e) {
        alert(e.target.innerHTML);
    };
    i++;
});
```

**Snippet:**

```js
var
  td = document.getElementById("id-742").children,
  i = 0;

Array.from(td).forEach(function() {
  td[i].onclick = function(e) {
    alert(e.target.innerHTML);
  };
  i++;
});
```

```css
td:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
td:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-uom_id="1" id="id-742">
      <td style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle; display: none;">1</td>
      <td style="width: 70%; text-align: left;" class="center">2</td>
      <td style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle;">3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's on click method more easily and use this to access the current td that was clicked.

```js
$(function(){
  
  $('tr#id-742 td').on('click',function(){
    console.log(this);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
   <tr data-uom_id="1" id="id-742">
     <td style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle;">1</td>
     <td style="width: 70%; text-align: left;" class="center">2</td>
     <td style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle;">3</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```